# Android studio create listener to variable

Tags: android, null, fragment, listener, customization

I have a question what is the best, easiest, shortest way to create custom(personal listener to value, I mean if I had some if statement that's will triggers when some boolean variable will changed.
The problem is the welcomeName initialize as null, so I need few milli seconds before I set a text.
So I want exectue a listener, that will do this when the welcomeName will not be null.
Thanks.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trinee);
    findViewById(R.id.trainee_home);
    findViewById(R.id.trainee_training);
    findViewById(R.id.trainee_cancel);
    setFragmentLayout();
    String nameLast="";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    welcomeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_string);
    nameLast = bundle.getBundle("personalBundle").getString("name")+
            " "+bundle.getBundle("personalBundle").getString("last");
    if(welcomeName!=null)
    {
        welcomeName.setText(nameLast);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all should run on the Main/UiThread, then the best way is using LiveData.

```
LiveData<Integer> mLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    mLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Integer value) {
            //"value" is the last value of "variable" you want to observe
        }
    });
}
```

then from anywhere in the same Activity/Fragment:

```
mLiveData.postValue(1);
....
mLiveData.postValue(2);
....
button.setOnClickListener(new ... {
    void onClick(View v) {
        mLiveData.postValue(3);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I misunderstanding the  mLiveData.postValue not recognize.
How it should looks like in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Not so working.. I will very thanksful if you can give me some example how do I need implement it

```
LiveData<String> mLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        String nameLast = "";
        TextView welcomeName;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                        welcomeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_string);
                        nameLast = bundle.getBundle("personalBundle").getString("name") +
                                " " + bundle.getBundle("personalBundle").getString("last");
            mLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(String str) {
                            welcomeName.setText(str);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You forgot to put a "mLiveData.postValue("test string");" somewhere... Maybe after the observe()? On the "onAttach()" event? Where you want...